# How do I go about using DLookup in a validation rule of a text box on a form in access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to use DLookup for a ValidationRule for a TextBox on a form in Access.

As per an example found on 
  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb240142.aspx)
I used

```
dlookup("ABKUERZUNG", "tblABKUERZUNG", "ABKUERZUNG=[Forms]![frmMutBetriebspunkt]![BP_ABKUERZUNG]") is null
```

Which does not work: **The expression you entered contains invalid syntax**.

Now, if someone knew what and where exactly this invalid syntax is, I'd be grateful.

Thanks
Rene

*edit*: corrected wrong ' to " (which was not the cause of the problem)

Comment: The example you pasted works. I copied and pasted all the object names. Do you have a validation Text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a function in code, the parameter separator is the comma(,), but in the GUI-editor it is the semicolon (;). This could be your syntax error.

So try:

```
=Dlookup("field";"table";"where")
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much. For the record, I used a 

=DLookUp("ABKUERZUNG";"tblBETRIEBSPUNKT";"ABKUERZUNG=[Forms]![frmMutBetriebspunkt]![BP_ABKUERZUNG]") Is Null

in order to make sure that ABKUERZUNG doesn't already exist in the table.

Comment: Er, what? Where is ";" a valid separater for function parameters? I cannot get it to be accepted anywhere in A2003. Is this, perhaps, a localization issue?

Comment: If you use a function in a calculated form-field or report-field, you have to use the ; like in Excel. But I can tell that only for the german version of Office.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED

For Code:

```
If IsNull(dlookup( _
"ABKUERZUNG", "tblABKUERZUNG", _
"ABKUERZUNG=[Forms]![frmMutBetriebspunkt]![BP_ABKUERZUNG]")) Then
```

For a Validation Rule:

```
dlookup("ABKUERZUNG", "tblABKUERZUNG", "ABKUERZUNG=[Forms]![frmMutBetriebspunkt]![BP_ABKUERZUNG]")=Null
```

Comment: I am trying to enter the expression into the ValidationRule, and trying to put the expression within an IF .. THEN .. TRUE END IF still brings the same error message.

Comment: Also, if I use the numeric primary key of the table instead of ABKUERZUNG, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Apologies - in that format delimters are not required. I note that you have a single quote at trhe start of the Where statement, it should be a double quote ("). Where do you have this code? In a module?

Comment: The ' is a mistake when I sort-of manually copied the text to stackoverflow. In the original code, I have a ". The code *is* the ValidationRule for a textBox on the form frmMutBetriebspunkt.

Answer (score 0):

You may want isolate the string you are creating for your filter, so you could check in the immediate window if the value is what you expect.

```
dim sFilter as String

sFilter = "ABKUERZUNG='" & [Forms]![frmMutBetriebspunkt]![BP_ABKUERZUNG] & "'"

dlookup("ABKUERZUNG", "tblABKUERZUNG", sFilter) is null
```

Comment: This is not true. Try it in the immediate window.

Comment: So use to doing it that way when coding, I didn't realize it is not required. Made changes.

Comment: Yes, but you're depending on the Access expression service to resolve the reference correctly in the guts of the DLookup() code, over which you have no control. I hardly ever use DLookup(), but if I did, I'd resolve the control reference before passing anything to it.