# How to set a validation rule on a field in Access using SQL Query?

Tags: sql, validation, ms-access, office365, ms-access-2016

I am using MS Access 2016 (Office 365) and I am currently facing an issue. Below is an example demonstrating this issue.

Here I created a Table named as **NodeFamilyLink**, which consists of two fields: NodeID and FamilyID as shown below.

[image: NodeFamilyLinkTable]

Now the NodeID's are obtained from another table NodeData, which consists of 3 fields: NodeID, NodeName and ParentID. In this table, all the nodes are defined initially as shown in the below image.

[image: NodeDataTable]

Now, what I want is while entering a number inside the NodeID column of the NodeFamilyLink table, if I enter a NodeID value which is not included in the ParentID column of the NodeData table, then that NodeID value will be considered as a valid one and rest other values will considered as invalid ones. So, I want to apply a validation rule on the NodeID field of the NodeFamilyLink table using a query. But the problem is that I didn't find an option to set the validation rule using query in ACCESS (as shown in the below image).

[image: ExpressionBuilder]

Although I can easily achieve the same by programming with the OLE-DB API (in VB.NET), but I want to know if there is any method with the help of which I can accomplish my task without writing any code for it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for the `DLookup()` function... This allows you to do a query type lookup in another table without writing code. [How do I go about using DLookup in a validation rule of a text box on a form in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667432/how-do-i-go-about-using-dlookup-in-a-validation-rule-of-a-text-box-on-a-form-in)

But an important distinction here is that the `DLookup()` function is only available in the validation context at the **form** level, not the **table** level.

[image: Not available at table level]

[image: Available at form level]

Depending on exactly where you are wanting to use the validation, this may give you a workable option for using query type lookups as part of your validation rules without writing code.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for a `CHECK` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE NodeFamilyLink
ADD CONSTRAINT myConstraintName
CHECK (
   NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM NodeFamilyLink INNER JOIN NodeData ON NodeData.ParentID = NodeFamilyLink.NodeID)
)
```

Note that these can only be added through ADO (by using `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute`), or when the database is using ANSI-92 compatible syntax.